# Facing issue with vertx junit configuratoin , error in vertx.deployVerticle , How to setup spring verticalfactory in deployment test

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, junit, vert.x

I want to test particular REST APIs written in vertx with spring boot.

below is test class

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class sampleTest {
    private Vertx vertx;
    private Integer port;

    @Before
    public void setUp(TestContext context) throws IOException {
        vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(0);
        port = socket.getLocalPort();
        socket.close();

        DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions()
                .setConfig(new JsonObject().put("http.port", port)
                );
        vertx.deployVerticle(sampleVerticle.class.getName(), options, context.asyncAssertSuccess());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(TestContext context) {
        vertx.close(context.asyncAssertSuccess());
    }

    @Test
    public void givenId_whenReceivedArticle_thenSuccess(TestContext testContext) {
        final Async async = testContext.async();

        vertx.createHttpClient()
                .getNow(port, "localhost", "/tracking/id/12345/12345/12345", response -> {
                    response.handler(responseBody -> {
                        testContext.assertTrue(responseBody.toString()
                                .contains("\"articalId\" : \"12345\""));
                        testContext.assertTrue(responseBody.toString()
                                .contains("\"pageId\" : \"12345\""));
                        testContext.assertTrue(responseBody.toString()
                                .contains("\"eventId\" : \"12345\""));
                        async.complete();
                    });
                });
    }

}
```

here im just checking url parameter.
Now when i run above test class it throws error

> java.lang.InstantiationException:
> com.articals.sampleVerticle

Below is sampleVerticle class where multiple routers are handled,

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
class sampleVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    private final Router router
    private final ArticalHandler articalHandler
    private final FailureHandler failureHandler
    private final MetricsHandler metricsHandler

    ClickVerticle(
            Router router,
            ArticalHandler articalHandler,
            FailureHandler failureHandler,
            MetricsHandler metricsHandler
    )
    {
        this.articalHandler= articalHandler
        this.router = router
        this.failureHandler = failureHandler
        this.metricsHandler = metricsHandler
    }


    @Override
    void start() throws Exception {

        router.get('/tracking/id/:articalId/:pageId/:eventId')
              .handler(articalHandler)
              .failureHandler(failureHandler)


        router.get('/metrics')
              .handler(metricsHandler)
              .failureHandler(failureHandler)

    }
}
```

If i include default constructor then i error

> Cannot invoke method get() on null object

I am following this example for unit testing
https://www.baeldung.com/vertx

Please help me with above issue.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

When you call `vertx.deploy` providing a class name, Vert.x expects the verticle class to have a no-arg constructor.

This is why the test fails with `InstantiationException`.

There is a `vertx.deploy` overload that takes a verticle object instance. You should create your instance first and then use this method :

```
sampleVerticle verticle = new sampleVerticle(router, handler1, ...)
vertx.deploy(verticle, options, context.asyncAssertSuccess());
```

To create the required router and handlers, you can either mock them (e.g. with Mockito) or start an embedded Spring application context.